# How to determine if a field is of type char[] (char array) in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I'm dynamically instantiating an object through reflection, by matching fields names to like-named keys in a Map.  One of the fields is a character array (char[]):

```
private char[] traceResponseStatus;
```

In the plinko iterator I have code for the types on the target class, eg.

```
Collection<Field> fields = EventUtil.getAllFields(MyClass.getClass()).values();
for (Field field : fields)
{
Object value = aMap.get(field.getName());
...
    else if (Date.class.equals(fieldClass))
    {
```

where the `fieldClass`, for example, would be `Date`

```
class MyClass
{
    private Date foo;
```

What's the expression to test if the fieldClass type is a char[]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bdean20 was on right track with the dupe suggestion, but the specific (and now obvious) solution:

```
if(char[].class.equals(field.getType()))
```

Test code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class Foo {

    char[] myChar;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Field field : Foo.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.format("Name: %s%n", field.getName());
            System.out.format("\tType: %s%n", field.getType());
            System.out.format("\tGenericType: %s%n", field.getGenericType());
            if(char[].class.equals(field.getClass()))
            {
                System.out.println("Class match");
            }
            if(char[].class.equals(field.getType()))
            {
                System.out.println("Type match");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: myChar
    Type: class [C
    GenericType: class [C
Type match
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you need to use is:

```
(variableName instanceof char[])
```

`instanceof` is an operator that returns a boolean indicating whether the object on the left is an instance of the type on the right i.e. this should return true for `variable instanceof Object` for everything except null, and in your case it will determine if your field is a char array.

Comment: I actually need a test for the Class of the field on the thing I'm populating (admittedly, my question was perfectly unclear).  I've updated the question to hopefully clarify.

Comment: The question now appears to be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868333/how-can-i-determine-the-type-of-a-generic-field-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
else if (traceResponseStatus instanceof char[])
```

Comment: I botched the question (see comment to @bdean20 above).