# Group by on JSON array using Underscore JS

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a JSON array object as follows:

```
var orders = [{
    orderId: 1,
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    address: {
        street: '123 Main Street',
        city: 'New York',
        zip: 10001
    }
}, {
    orderId: 2,
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    address: {
        street: '456 Main Street',
        city: 'New York',
        zip: 10001
    }
}, {
    orderId: 3,
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    address: {
        street: '123 Main Street',
        city: 'New York',
        zip: 10001
    }
}, {
    orderId: 4,
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    address: {
        street: '123 Main Street',
        city: 'New York',
        zip: 10002
    }
}];
```

I am trying to use `underscore.js` to create a new array object, grouped by the address to meet the use case of displaying all orders that have been shipped to `123 Main Street, New York, 1001`.

Is `underscore.js` the right approach to do this? If so, how should I do so? Any hints will be helpful.

Comment: What would be the output of this? Object pointing to arrays? What would you key the objects by? Arrays of Arrays?

Comment: @JuanMendes - the output would be an array of arrays.  I'm trying the suggestion you made about _.groupBy now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`_.groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy)

```
console.log(_.groupBy(orders, function(obj){
    return obj.address.street + '|' + obj.address.city + '|' + obj.address.zip;
}));
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/gc47ruyL/1/

This example assumes you cannot have a `|` in an address, you may need a better separator, or use `JSON.stringify`:

```
console.log(_.groupBy(orders, function(obj){
    return JSON.stringify([obj.address.street, obj.address.city, obj.address.zip]);
}));
```

Comment: thanks @JuanMendes - I think groupBy will solve my problem.  The JSON I posted above was an over simplified version of what I have so I am trying to put the pieces together. I will update here either way to inform if it works or not. Thanks again - everyone - for the help.

Comment: `return JSON.stringify(…)` always works for escaping if you don't want to choose a specific separator.

Comment: @Bergi, except that there's no guarantee of the order of properties, two similar objects could end up serializing differently.

Comment: @JuanMendes: Actually I meant to `stringify` each string on its own, or maybe an array of them, to get a concatenation like in your answer. I didn't even think of the possibility to `JSON.stringify(obj.address)`, which would indeed suffer from the mentioned problem.

Comment: @Bergi I still don't see what you mean with using `JSON.stringify` to get the group key. Do you mind maybe editing the answer and adding your alternative? My main concern is the case where you have two objects `{a: "aa", b: "aa"}` and `{a: "a", b: "aaa"}` or `{a: "a|", b: "b"}` and `{a: "a", b: "|b"}`

Comment: @Bergi I see: the quotes around each item make it safe from repeated characters at the edges of properties, and the array keeps the order

Comment: @JuanMendes - thanks for suggesting to use _.groupBy - it was exactly what I needed.  I am a new user here and am amazed by the help I was provided. I will make every effort to contribute back.

Comment: @orchard Same thing happened to me 5 years ago, I've been addicted since http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868333/how-can-i-determine-the-type-of-a-generic-field-in-java

Answer (score 2):

If you already have underscore in your page, you could use

```
var filteredOrders = _.filter(orders, function(order){
  return (order.address.street === '123 Main Street') &&
          (order.address.city === 'New York') &&
          (order.address.zip === 10001);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg22wqq0/1/)

Comment: Thanks @amit_g - that is helpful, but this would work for this specific example where there is only 1 address.  The JSON example I posted was representative of an array which could contain multiple users with different addresses.

I need to be able to compare the address object across all users, so that I can find all users who share the same address.

Comment: @orchard, please update the question with a sample to demonstrate this requirement.

Comment: @JordanGray Actually it cannot be easily extended, it's easy if you know what you're searching for, otherwise, some heavy work is needed to find duplicates

Comment: @JuanMendes Good point; I neglected to consider excluding duplicates. Still, I feel that Amit deserves some credit for answering what was asked. :)

Comment: @JordanGray - the first thing I tried was to mark the answer as helpful :) but I am a new user and found that I don't have the required reputation (15 points) to do so ... I completely concur Amit's response is very helpful indeed.

Comment: @amit_g - thanks for the fiddle.  It helps and I'm trying to make it meet the requirement I had described above ...

Comment: @JuanMendes - thanks for the feedback. However in my JSON, I am guaranteed not to have duplicates so filtering those out would not be a concern.  You made a perfectly valid point though.

Comment: @orchard Ah, I see—sorry, I hadn't considered that you might not have the upvote privilege. In that case, please consider my earlier comment fully retracted.

Comment: @orchard Both of you misunderstood what I said, my point is that you have to scan the array once, and then find all the objects with the same address, duplicates was not the best word