# Why does the outer class appear twice in the generic type name?

Tags: java, reflection, code-generation

Q: Why does the name of the containing class appear twice?

Context: I'm generating code and the goal is to get the declaration of the field, as written in the source (fully qualified is fine, but I need the type parameter): `test.Foo.Bar<java.lang.String>`

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class Foo
{
  public static class Bar<TYPE> {}

  private Bar<String> bar;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Field field = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("bar");
    Type genericType = field.getGenericType();
    Type type = field.getType();

    System.out.println("genericType: " + genericType.getTypeName());
    System.out.println("       type: " + type.getTypeName());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
genericType: test.Foo.test.Foo$Bar<java.lang.String>
       type: test.Foo$Bar
```

UPDATE:
Thank you everyone for your input. Since this question was marked as duplicate, I posted my current working solution [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45085377/1124509).

Comment: Also see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054213.

Comment: @Radiodef good catch, that issue seems to be identical to my question. So it is a bug? (convert to answer)

Comment: It probably should be considered a bug, but there isn't really a standardized specification for `String` representations of types. [`getTypeName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html#getTypeName--) doesn't specify any particular requirements and neither does `toString`. It's not a very well-developed section of the API.

Answer (score 3):

genericType is instance of ParameterizedTypeImpl

the toString() method returns ownerType class' name and then rawType classname.

The decompiled piece of the code

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder var1 = new StringBuilder();
    if(this.ownerType != null) {
        if(this.ownerType instanceof Class) {
            var1.append(((Class)this.ownerType).getName()); //<---
        } else {
            var1.append(this.ownerType.toString());
        }

        var1.append(".");
        if(this.ownerType instanceof ParameterizedTypeImpl) {
            var1.append(this.rawType.getName().replace(((ParameterizedTypeImpl)this.ownerType).rawType.getName() + "$", ""));
        } else {
            var1.append(this.rawType.getName()); //<------------
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for investigating. I'm still wondering why it is like that. How is this useful? How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: They try to provide more info - for your question you can check and skip `        System.out.println("raw type from generic: " + ((ParameterizedTypeImpl)genericType).getRawType());`

Comment: ParameterizedTypeImpl is a sun class, I would prefer not to use it.

Comment: Type is an Interface and implementation could be platform dependent or VM dependent.

Comment: You can try to subtract `field.getDeclaringClass().getName()` from the `genericType.getTypeName()` but again actual toString() is based on VM dependent implementation

Comment: You are right, and "returns a string describing this type" is not really a very strict contract... Leaves me wondering how people do it. Going the hackish way for now.

Comment: @Zalumon You don't need `ParameterizedTypeImpl`, just use its JDK interface `ParameterizedType`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for the pointer, I used it in my implementation, as posted in the update of the question.