# Extract Multiple Generic Types from a Field in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics

I'm using Spring boot and I'm doing reflection to extract classes within my package ending with "Repository" and all fields declared as `MyGenericClass<T,R>`. My problem is that I am unable to extract `ClassA` and `ClassB` from `myField`

```
public class ContainerRepository{
private MyGenericClass<ClassA, ClassB> myField;}
```

I wish to run the same code against:

```
public class ProcessRepository{
private MyGenericClass<ClassC, ClassD> anotherField;}
```

and get`ClassC` and `ClassD` from `anotherField`

Comment: You cannot do that. Reflection retrieves the runtime type, and due to type erasure, the generic class parameters will be gone. See http://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine the type of a generic field in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868333/how-can-i-determine-the-type-of-a-generic-field-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, you can't infer generics at run time using Reflection. However, you can mark your field types easily as a instance variable(quite a hack but not sure if it helps).

```
public class MyGenericClass<M, N> {

    private M mType;
    private N nType;

    MyGenericClass (M m, N n){
        this.mType = m;
        this.nType = n;
    }

    public Class<?> getMType(){
        return this.mType.getClass();
    }

    public Class<?> getNType(){
        return this.nType.getClass();
    }

}
```

**Reference below:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26088911/2931410

Comment: you could also just return `Class<?>` in you get methods